# Linq ?? operator means

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Good Day.

Sorry before i'm a beginner on linq. can i ask what is the meaning of ?? in linq

```html
.Where(w => ((w.BalancedDate ?? w.OriginalDateByAMT) >= filter.start_date && (w.BalancedDate ?? w.OriginalDateByAMT) <= filter.end_date) || w.ReplaceByEHValidation == true)
```

Thanks

Comment: @Aomine so it means that if w.BalancedDate is null then it will be replaced by w.OriginalDateByAMT value?

Comment: Correct, if `w.BalancedDate` is null then `w.OriginalDateByAMT` will be used for the comparison.

Comment: @randy yes that's what it means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a linq operator, but it means if the left hand property is null, then use the right hand property.

Comment: So its like COALESCE or ISNULL on SQL?

Comment: @Randy, Exactly, in fact it's call the null coalescing operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 1):

If the value on the left side of ?? is null, then it takes the value of the right side.

I.e.

> var x = y ?? z;

If y is not null then x=y otherwise x=z

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question was already answered on the link shared on the comments. It is a Nullable type or null-coalescing, it returns the left value if not null or else it returns the right one.